# CSS not working properly in XSLT

Tags: html, css, xslt

I used the below code to display a XML file as HTML using XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="Report/Scripts">
<html>
   <head>
   <title>Mobiuss.rtp Test Execution Results</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="xmlstyle.css" />
   </head>
   <body>
   <xsl:for-each select="Script">
   <h1><xsl:value-of select="@File"/></h1>
   Execution log
   <br>
   </br>
   <table class="sortable">
   <tr>
   <th>Time</th>
   <th>Position</th>
   <th>Type</th>
   <th>Message</th>
   </tr>
   <xsl:for-each select="Message">
   <tr>
   <td> <xsl:value-of select="@Time"/></td>
   <td>Line <xsl:value-of select="@Line"/></td>
   <td> <xsl:value-of select="@Type"/></td>
   <td> <xsl:value-of select="@Message"/></td>
   </tr>
   </xsl:for-each>
   </table>
   </xsl:for-each>       
   </body>
</html>   
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The above code displays the XML file as html it creates around 4 tables(depends on the XML)
But for some reason I don't know the first table alone is following the CSS all other tables does not get styled.

The CSS code goes here:

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
.sortable {width:100%; height:40px; border:1px solid #ccc; background-color:#EEE0E5}
.sortable th {padding:4px 6px 6px; background:#444; color:#fff; text-align:center;     color:#ccc}
.sortable td {padding:2px 4px 4px; background:#fff; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; overflow:auto}
.sortable .head {background:#444 url(images/sort.gif) 6px center no-repeat; cursor:pointer; padding-left:18px}
.sortable .desc {background:#222 url(images/desc.gif) 6px center no-repeat; cursor:pointer; padding-left:18px}
.sortable .asc {background:#222 url(images/asc.gif) 6px  center no-repeat; cursor:pointer; padding-left:18px}
.sortable .head:hover, .sortable .desc:hover, .sortable .asc:hover {color:#fff}
.sortable .even td {background:#f2f2f2}
.sortable .odd td {background:#fff}
```

please guide me what to change in my code so that all the tables that gets created are properly styled.

Comment: The problem is probably in the css itself. Can you post that?

Comment: @JAR.JAR.beans Edited with CSS code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is a simple test: http://jsbin.com/azaqog/1/ seems to be working fine. The issue you are facing is not evident in the provided data.

The one thing I can now suspect is that the data you are parsing from the XML contains something that causing the final HTML to be invalid. I suggest that you parse the XML+XSLT into a raw text file, and look at the output. You should see something there that is breaking your html.

Comment: Thanks i found out that the data in the xml file is making it invalid the second table contains lot of data based on the timings so it is altering the whole table.. thanks for the answer

Comment: can you provide me something like overflow:scroll so that i can scroll the single cell of the table if it exceeds the width and height

Comment: Trini, you should probably open a new and relevant question. overflow:scroll works on div, so if you want a cell to scroll, you can  embed a div in the td.